# Python - importing a txt.file seperated by commas and whitespaces

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I need to import a .txt file with some statistics about weather. The values however are seperated by a comma followed by three spaces. When I try to remove this by adding sep="   " or ",   " I get an error.

```html
from tkinter.ttk import Separator
import pandas as pd

# Import dataset
df = pd.read_csv("etmgeg_235.txt")

# Drop eventual null values
df.isnull().sum()
df.dropna

#Show correlations
cr = df.corr()
print(cr)
```

'

The program "works" when importing the .txt file, but then I get one correlation with NaN and one with a value of 1.0.

The dataset looks like this: "235,19060101,  113,   67,   67,   87,   12,   51,    1,     ,     ,  -28, etc...." with a few more whitespaces between them. How do I import this dataset correctly?

Comment: if you have a random number of white spaces and are sure that your values are all numeric, then you can read as usual (faster than python engine) and then strip the columns that are type `object` and convert them to numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pd.read_csv` with `engine='python'` to set a regex separator. Something like:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep=r',\s*', engine='python')
```

Comment: Works like a charm, I'll read some more into regex seperators. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

pandas `read_csv` allows you to use regex, so something like

```py
df = pd.read_csv("etmgeg_235.txt", sep="[,\s]+", engine="python")
```

should work. Note that you will have to use the `python` engine to use regex.